# python -m spacy download en too slow how to speed up

Tags: python, spacy

The speed is less 10KB/s when I run `python -m spacy download en`
For example:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/simple/
Collecting en_core_web_sm==2.1.0 from https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm==2.1.0
Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz (11.1MB)
29% |█████████▍ | 3.2MB 8.0kB/s eta 0:16:16
```

And then the connection will break because of reading time out.
But I can download *en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz* in my browser quickly.
how can I use *en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz* directly by using a command line such as

```
python -m spacy install ./en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz
```

Comment: try pip install ./en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

Just use [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) for downloading the file, and then you can download it faster from colab, use the wget command to download the file on colab.

```
!wget <download URL>
```

Download the file from colab, then install it with pip in your python environment

```
pip install <location of the file>
```